# Trouble with a function javascript for increment or decrement date

Tags: javascript, function, date, onclick

I met a trouble with a function I try to build.

In fact I have several dates that should be changed of + x days or - x days.

But not all dates should be changed. BEcause I have some dates that are confirmed.

In fact in mysql I have date_action and date_validation column.

When data_validation ='0000-00-00' it mean that it is not confirmed . When it's equal to a date it mean that it is validated.

In my page I display many information. I would like to change if possible all dates that are not validated but I'm verry lost I've build that function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lz(x){
return x.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,'0$1')
}

    function addday() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");


            items[0] = document.getElementById("date" + (1)).value;


            items[1] = document.getElementById("date" + (2)).value;


            items[2] = document.getElementById("date" + (3)).value;


            items[3] = document.getElementById("date" + (4)).value;


            items[4] = document.getElementById("date" + (5)).value;


            items[5] = document.getElementById("date" + (6)).value;


            items[6] = document.getElementById("date" + (7)).value;


            items[7] = document.getElementById("date" + (8)).value;


            items[8] = document.getElementById("date" + (9)).value;


            items[9] = document.getElementById("date" + (10)).value;



        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
             var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb);
            nb=document.getElementById('nb').value;

                itemCount[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear()
        }


       return items;
           }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function subday() {
        var items = new Array();
        var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");


            items[0] = document.getElementById("date" + (1)).value;


            items[1] = document.getElementById("date" + (2)).value;


            items[2] = document.getElementById("date" + (3)).value;


            items[3] = document.getElementById("date" + (4)).value;


            items[4] = document.getElementById("date" + (5)).value;


            items[5] = document.getElementById("date" + (6)).value;


            items[6] = document.getElementById("date" + (7)).value;


            items[7] = document.getElementById("date" + (8)).value;


            items[8] = document.getElementById("date" + (9)).value;


            items[9] = document.getElementById("date" + (10)).value;





        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
            items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i + 1)).value;
            var itemDtParts = items[i].split("-");
             var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ -nb);
            nb=document.getElementById('nb').value;

                itemCount[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear()
        }


       return items;
           }

</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle. In fact it select good dates using the query of mysql like that:

```
  <?php  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE n_doss='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n_doss'])."' AND qualite='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['qualite'])."' AND liasse='".$_GET['liasse']."' AND `date_validation`='0000-00-00' ORDER BY `date_action` ASC" ;
  $rules2=mysql_query($sql2) ; $i2=0;
  while($data2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rules2)) {?>

            items[<?php echo $i2 ; ?>] = document.getElementById("date" + (<?php echo ++$i2 ; ?>)).value;

<?php }?>
```

but it replace other dates that are not concerned by this changement.

here is the jsfiddle for more precision http://jsfiddle.net/pgLpj/

Answer (score 0):

According to the tags of your post, I assume you want to change non-validated dates using JavaScript (with jQuery as you use the Datepicker).

According to the jsFiddle you linked, date_validation is displayed either as a date or as a text that does not match the regexp `/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/`.

To test if the date was confirmed, as you use indexes a lot and using the variable `i` from inside the loop and the naming structure of your inputs:

```
if(!$('input[name="data['+i+'][date_validation]"]').val().match('/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/')) {
  //date not confirmed > add the date element to the to-be-returned array
  items.push($('input[name="data['+i+'][date]"]')); //or use items[i]=$('#date'+(i+1)) as you did in your post
}
```

Hope this helps!